# Switching from windows to ubuntu on a multi drives pc environment

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows

I have read a lot of answers on the subject about this migration, but nothing about the capability to replace win on a multi drives/partionned machine.
I have 5 drives in my pc:
2x 128 go ssd, 2x nvme ssd (256Go & 512Go), 1x 2to hdd
I was thinking installing ubuntu on the 1st ssd (128go) after saving windows & reformating it
I just wonder if grub is seen them as dev/hda....  or not, and btw, access them once ubuntu is installed.
Rgds

Comment: Does your PC use (U)EFI ?

Comment: And are drives gpt partitioned or MBR(msdos) partitioned. UEFI uses gpt, but Ubuntu will use MBR with UEFI and probably should not. Drives are not hda, but sda or NVMe now. But grub is before mount as sda, and see drives as (hd0) and partitions as (hd0,1) or (hd0,gpt1) or (hd0,msdos1).  Older versions of Ubuntu always install grub to first drive, if nvme, it is usually first. First drive is defined by BIOS/UEFI as hd0. Choice of drive to install grub bootloader still shown in UEFI, but does not work with Ubiquity installer.Use live installer and test system in live mode, before anything else.

Comment: My win11 boot drive is GPT and all the others are MBR. Nvme drives are 3 &  4 in sequence (seen by aoeim partition assistant). Anyway i can manage to change my boot drive to another MBR drive. I have enough space to move data on the other drives and in case of failure, i can switch back to win by  booting on the previous drive. tks for help